# Como remover as aspas duplas de um array JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ultimamente venho tentando usar um grafico do Highcharts porem venho enfrentando um problema,
onde eu passo o valor para geração do grafico não aceita "", e minha array que eu capturo do php é montada com "" por exemplo "1","2","3" e ai não funciona meu codigo eu preciso que seja 1,2,3 na array
segue meu codigo a seguir

```
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      rcbCom = this.responseText;              // rcbCom = recebe o conteudo da variaves do php e começa a fazer a quebra da informação, rcb = recebe
      var spCom = rcbCom.split("|");           // spCom = dividi as colunas separando onde estao as | ,    sp=Separacao
      dataon[0]=  spCom[0].split(",");         // numero do simcon
      sinal[0]= spCom[1].split(",");
      on[0]= spCom[2].split(",");


      Highcharts.chart('graf', {

  title: {
    text: 'QUEDAS DE CONEXÃO'
  },

  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,
    type: 'logarithmic',
    accessibility: {
      rangeDescription: 'Range: 1 to 10'
    }
  },

  yAxis: {
    type: 'logarithmic',
    minorTickInterval: 0.1,
    accessibility: {
      rangeDescription: 'Range: 0.1 to 1000'
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br />',
    pointFormat: 'x = {point.x}, y = {point.y}'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [1,2,3,4], //aqui preciso passar minha variavel on[0] porem com aspas ela não funciona
    pointStart: 1
  }]
});



    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","../GrafCom/php/graf.php?cod="+cod+"&srv="+srv+"&data1="+date1+"&data2="+date2+"&con="+nCon, true);       //para capturar o valor da variavel cd e mandar para o php
  xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: cadê o código do PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, minha sugestão para você é que insira um laço para iterar sobre a array logo após recebê-la, convertendo-a em uma array numérica.

Experimente o snippet a seguir, substituindo 'main' pelo nome associado a sua array:

`var main = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];`

`var cMain = main.map(Number)`

Ou, pode usar um laço 'for', caso não queira criar outra variável:

`var main = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];`

`for (let i = 0; i < main.length; i++) {main[i] = Number(main[i])}`

Se desejar melhor desempenho, declare 'let i' fora do laço de repetição, usando '{}' para controlar o scope.

Ps: Não tenho muito conhecimento sobre o contexto do seu código, mas espero que isto ajude.